# postgresql closed connection : could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo-8

I have 3 **odoos** running normal into ec2 in aws with ubuntu16, and **postgresql 9.5**, but days ago 1 odoo instance died, in my log odoo I saw:

```
2018-01-11 06:15:56,343 28311 ERROR ? openerp.addons.bus.bus: Bus.loop error, sleep and retry
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/bus/bus.py", line 136, in run
    self.loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/bus/bus.py", line 122, in loop
    conn.poll()
OperationalError: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly

2018-01-11 06:15:58,283 28311 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Initiating shutdown
```

In my postgresql log I get:

```
2018-01-11 01:07:52 -05 LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2018-01-11 01:15:56 -05 LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2018-01-11 01:15:56 -05 LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2018-01-11 01:15:56 -05 LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2018-01-11 01:15:56 -05 FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2018-01-11 01:15:56 -05 FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2018-01-11 01:15:56 -05 LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2018-01-11 01:15:56 -05 FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2018-01-11 01:15:56 -05 FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2018-01-11 01:15:56 -05 FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2018-01-11 01:15:56 -05 FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2018-01-11 01:15:56 -05 LOG:  shutting down
2018-01-11 01:15:56 -05 LOG:  database system is shut down
2018-01-11 01:16:53 -05 LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-01-11 01:15:56 -05
2018-01-11 01:16:53 -05 LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2018-01-11 01:16:53 -05 LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2018-01-11 01:16:53 -05 LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2018-01-11 01:16:53 -05 LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

I have other two odoo's running into this server, and the others continues running without problems , then about 10 a.m.  I reboot odoo and this dead odoo , started . I don't know if odoo closed the connection withouth telling anything to postgres or postgres closed the connection

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The message

```
could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

in the PostgreSQL log means that the client end of the connection has vanished without properly closing the database session.

From the PostgreSQL side, this has nothing to do with the PostgreSQL shutdown.